# "bash: export: ... not a valid identifier" in CLI of git-bash shell "MINGW64" on Windows 10

Tags: bash, terminal, path, git-bash, mingw-w64

Using [git for Windows](https://github.com/git-for-windows), I always get the following output when opening a new git-bash terminal:

```
bash: export: `C:\Users\username\Projects\proj1\src\packages\;C:\Users\username\Projects\proj2\MachineLearning\;C:\Users\username\Projects\proj2\MachineLearning\azure_components\': not a valid identifier
```

Next, I examined the [PATH](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/aix/7.2?topic=accounts-path-environment-variable) variable via `echo $PATH`:

```
C:\Users\username\Projects\proj1-venv/Scripts:/c/Users/username/bin:/mingw64/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/mingw64/bin:/usr/bin:/c/Users/username/bin:/c/WINDOWS/system32:/c/WINDOWS:/c/WINDOWS/System32/Wbem:/c/WINDOWS/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0:/c/WINDOWS/System32/OpenSSH:/c/Program Files/dotnet:/c/ProgramData/chocolatey/bin:/cmd:/c/users/username/.pyenv/pyenv-win/versions/3.9.0a4/Scripts:/c/Program Files/PuTTY:/c/Program Files/Amazon/AWSCLIV2:/c/ProgramData/chocolatey/lib/gsudo/bin:/c/Program Files/Amazon/AWSSAMCLI/bin:/c/Users/username/AppData/Local/Terraform:/c/Users/username/AppData/Local/iPython:/c/Program Files/Docker/Docker/resources/bin:/c/ProgramData/DockerDesktop/version-bin:/c/Program Files/Microsoft SQL Server/130/Tools/Binn:/c/Program Files/Microsoft SQL Server/Client SDK/ODBC/170/Tools/Binn:/c/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft SQL Server/150/DTS/Binn:/c/Program Files/Azure Data Studio/bin:/c/Users/username/.pyenv/pyenv-win/bin:/c/Users/username/.pyenv/pyenv-win/shims:/c/Users/username/.pyenv/pyenv-win/bin:/c/Users/username/.pyenv/pyenv-win/shims:/c/Users/username/AppData/Local/Microsoft/WindowsApps:/c/Users/username/AppData/Local/Programs/Microsoft_VS_Code/bin:/c/Users/username/.pyenv/pyenv-win/bin:/c/Users/username/.pyenv/pyenv-win/shims:/c/Users/username/AppData/Local/Pandoc:/c/texlive/2021/bin/win32:/c/Users/username/AppData/Local/Terraform:/c/Users/username/AppData/Local/iPython:/c/Users/username/.dotnet/tools:/c/Program Files/Azure Data Studio/bin:/usr/bin/vendor_perl:/usr/bin/core_perl
```

I tried to export the content of `$PATH` explicitely using `export $PATH` which throws the same error `bash: export: ... not a valid identifier` many times over:

```
bash: export: `C:\Users\username\Projects\proj1-venv/Scripts:/c/Users/username/bin:/mingw64/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/mingw64/bin:/usr/bin:/c/Users/username/bin:/c/WINDOWS/system32:/c/WINDOWS:/c/WINDOWS/System32/Wbem:/c/WINDOWS/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0:/c/WINDOWS/System32/OpenSSH:/c/Program': not a valid identifier
bash: export: `Files/dotnet:/c/ProgramData/chocolatey/bin:/cmd:/c/users/username/.pyenv/pyenv-win/versions/3.9.0a4/Scripts:/c/Program': not a valid identifier
bash: export: `Files/PuTTY:/c/Program': not a valid identifier
bash: export: `Files/Amazon/AWSCLIV2:/c/ProgramData/chocolatey/lib/gsudo/bin:/c/Program': not a valid identifier
bash: export: `Files/Amazon/AWSSAMCLI/bin:/c/Users/username/AppData/Local/Terraform:/c/Users/username/AppData/Local/iPython:/c/Program': not a valid identifier
bash: export: `Files/Docker/Docker/resources/bin:/c/ProgramData/DockerDesktop/version-bin:/c/Program': not a valid identifier
bash: export: `Files/Microsoft': not a valid identifier
bash: export: `Server/130/Tools/Binn:/c/Program': not a valid identifier
bash: export: `Files/Microsoft': not a valid identifier
bash: export: `Server/Client': not a valid identifier
bash: export: `SDK/ODBC/170/Tools/Binn:/c/Program': not a valid identifier
bash: export: `(x86)/Microsoft': not a valid identifier
bash: export: `Server/150/DTS/Binn:/c/Program': not a valid identifier
bash: export: `Files/Azure': not a valid identifier
bash: export: `Studio/bin:/c/Users/username/.pyenv/pyenv-win/bin:/c/Users/username/.pyenv/pyenv-win/shims:/c/Users/username/.pyenv/pyenv-win/bin:/c/Users/username/.pyenv/pyenv-win/shims:/c/Users/username/AppData/Local/Microsoft/WindowsApps:/c/Users/username/AppData/Local/Programs/Microsoft_VS_Code/bin:/c/Users/username/.pyenv/pyenv-win/bin:/c/Users/username/.pyenv/pyenv-win/shims:/c/Users/username/AppData/Local/Pandoc:/c/texlive/2021/bin/win32:/c/Users/username/AppData/Local/Terraform:/c/Users/username/AppData/Local/iPython:/c/Users/username/.dotnet/tools:/c/Program': not a valid identifier
bash: export: `Files/Azure': not a valid identifier
bash: export: `Studio/bin:/usr/bin/vendor_perl:/usr/bin/core_perl': not a valid identifier
```

I suspect that it is related to the **space characters** in many of the paths, which is quite common on Windows, but not liked by UNIX-systems.

Assuming this is the culprit, how would I best get around this issue?
If something else is responsible for this undesired behavior, I would also like to understand that.

Comment: It should be `export PATH` as you are exporting the 'PATH' variable, not `export $PATH`.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I searched all my `.bash..` - scripts in the `~` - folder and corrected these errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As correctly pointed out in the first comment under my OP by @Zilog80, I had to check and remove all `$` after the `export`-command in the following `bash` start-up scripts:

1. .bashrc
2. .bash_profile
3. .profile

In my case, all the fuss boiled down to the following line in my `~/.bashrc` - script:

```
export $PYTHONPATH
```

This had to be replaced with

```
export PYTHONPATH
```

Now, opening a new terminal-session does not throw these *"bash: export: … not a valid identifier"* - errors anymore.